# Kubernetes Dashboard Update Deployment Issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

When I am trying to update the deployment by uploading an **updated deployment.yaml**, there is an error showing `deployments.apps {my-app-name} already exists`.

I know that I can update the image version from deployment, but I want to do all the work using yaml, so that I can keep track of what I am doing.

Thanks

p.s. I do not have console access to that machine, only the dashboard web interface.

Answer (score 0):

please try following on command line :

`kubectl apply -f  deployment.yaml -n <namespace name>`

To do this from dashboard by uploading the yaml file -

delete your existing deployment and upload the modified file. While your deployment is running, you cannot upload the file for the same deployment again.

Comment: Hi there, I cannot access the terminal, so running kubectl is not an option

Comment: Deleting the deployment will result in a program downtime, which is not ideal. I don't know whether it is by design or bug that I cannot update the deployment using `+ CREATE` button.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find the other way as to update deployment through the Dashboard WEB UI submenu: `Deployments > View/edit YAML`.Seems that POST request within `https://Web_ui_dashboard_IP/api/v1/appdeploymentfromfile` does not support deployment modification.